# Avoid iPhone lock on iPod sleep

Tags: iphone, screen-lock

Is there a way to prevent the iPhone from locking when "Sleep iPod" is activated as a timer?

I have this alarm clock app (SleepCycle) that needs to be running on an unlocked iPhone to pick up movement during the night. If I also want to listen to music or an audiobook while falling asleep, I set the clock timer to sleep iPod after a certain interval, but this seems to also lock the iPhone, even if I've set auto-lock to never. Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t believe that theres a way to avoid that. If the application doesn’t do it on its own, you are out of luck.

Comment: @Martín Marconcini: Thanks, I didn't expect it either, but it never hurts to ask...=) The app stays unlocked most of the time on its own, but the Sleep iPod defeats it every time...=(

Comment: May I suggest you contact the author of the application, maybe he/she can do something about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can ask the developer of SleepCycle to put some iPod scheduling controls into the app? That seems like the best solution.

I do know of one other solution, but I'm afraid it's a Jailbreak app. There's a paid app in Cydia called `SBSchedule`, which (when combined with the free `SBSettings` and `SBSettings iPod toggle`) can toggle the iPod off on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I just fired off an e-mail to the SleepCycle developer, let's see if it works. Great that there's an alternative, but I prefer to run my phone non-jailbroken. Currently my solution is listening to a short playlist or just the end of one so that it automatically goes quiet...=)

Comment: Maybe you could create a Smart Playlist that's limited to last only a certain length of time?